# Hide back button in Azure Active Directory login page

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, adal, adal.js

We have implemented ADAL js in our angular web app.

I wonder if Is there any config to hide the back ('Atrás' in the picture) button at the login page?
[image]

to be like:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, there's not option to hide the "back" button.

Comment: Thanks Philippe .. then why some apps doesnt show this back button?