# "Back" button in Microsoft Sign in page

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We are implementing web application for providing Outlook based calendar service.
Regarding to this work, I have two questions about Microsoft login page.

(Q1) Why the "Back" button is shown on Microsoft login page?
I've seen some web apps doesn't show "Back" button. What's the difference?

(Q2) It seems that go through one another page before going to the last page shown.
Is it normal?

(Q3) Is available to hide "Back" button in Microsoft login page?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a minimum working example and you will always generate more answers by providing some screenshots! :)

Comment: Thanks PySeeker, but..
My company's internal security policies prevent uploading screenshot images to this page.
Screenshots seems to be similar to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57810154/hide-back-button-in-azure-active-directory-login-page/57813056#57813056